# How can I replace command git log --first-parent (any analogues?)

Tags: git

I have an old git version in CI and can't update it

git version: 1.8.3.1

but I need this command **git log --first-parent**

Are there any analogues of this command that can be used in versions up to 1.8.3.1?

Comment: The source code of Git is freely available. Many commands are just shell scripts. Maybe you can copy it from a more recent version.

Comment: `git log --first-parent` first appeared in Git version 1.5.1. You should have it in 1.8.3.1.